# Drop down menu repeating its animation several times

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery drop down menu which has animated when we hover the menu, the problem is little difficult to explain. Its been continued animation when we hover the top menu several times, you can see that by move your cursor to 'Our Services', 'Locations' menu continuously around 10, 15 times.

Here is the JSfiddle you can check.. http://jsfiddle.net/bKxXZ/13/

the JQuery code is given below (earlier the code was suggested one of my stack friend gilly3)

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.topnav li:has(.subnav)").hover(function() {
        $("ul.subnav", this).slideDown('fast').show();
    }, function() {
        $("ul.subnav", this).slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `stop(true,true)` function like this:

```
$(function() {
$("ul.topnav li:has(.subnav)").hover(function() {
    $("ul.subnav", this).stop(true,true).slideDown('fast').show();
}, function() {
    $("ul.subnav", this).slideUp('slow');
});
});
```

Note it's placement before `slideDown`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stop(true, true) function before running the next animation to avoid animations queuing up see update here: http://jsfiddle.net/bKxXZ/15/